# Converting duration in varchar to number type and minutes

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm struggling with this.

- I have a column in Snowflake called DURATION, it is VARCHAR type.
- The values include basically number in days, hours, minutes, seconds. The value could include either just the number with one unit of time (day or hour or minute or second) such as 3 hours or 14 minutes or 3 seconds or it could include the combination of either all units of time or a few such as 1 day 3 hours 35 minutes or 1 hour 9 minutes or 45 minutes 1 second.
- The value could also be blank or invalid such as text or it could be indicating day, hour or minute but without a number (see the last 3 rows in the table below).

I would greatly appreciate it if you guys could help me with the following:

- in SNOWFLAKE, convert all valid values to number type and normalize them to minutes (e.g. the resulted value for 7 Hours and 13 Minutes would be 433).

Thanks a lot, guys!

| **DURATION** |
| --- |
| 1 Second |
| 10 Seconds |
| 1 Minute |
| 3 Minutes |
| 20 Minutes |
| 1 Hour |
| 2 Hours |
| 7 Hours 13 Minutes |
| 1 Hour 1 Minute |
| 1 Day |
| 1 Day 1 Hour |
| 1 Day 1 Hour 1 Minute |
| 1 Day 10 Hours |
| 2 Days 1 Hour |
| 3 Days 9 Hours |
| 1 Day 3 Hours 45 Minutes |
| Duration (invalid) |
|  |
| Days |
| Day Minute |
| Minutes |

I tried many things using regex_substr, try_to_number, coalesce functions in CASE statements but I'm getting either 0s or NULL for all values. Very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use STRTOK_TO_ARRAY in a CTE subquery or put into a temp table. Then you could use ARRAY_POSITION to find the labels and the index one less than the label should be the value. Those values could be put into separate columns with a case for each label pulling the found values. The case statements could be computed columns if you insert the results of the first query into a table. From there you can concatenate colons and cast to a time type and use datediff, or do the arithmetic to calculate the minutes.

Comment: Use comment instead of posting it as answer